# Conditional regex not working

Tags: regex

I am new to conditional regex. 
I want to match digits only if the word 'Box' exists before it. Here is my regex and input

```
^RR\s+(?<RR>[0-9]+)(?<POBox>(?<=\sBox\s)[0-9]+).*$
```

Should match both of the following:

```
RR 1 Box 23
RR 1
```

It should not match:

```
RR 1 23
RR 1 OtherText 23
```

So `23` should be only matched if word `Box` exists before `23`.

The above regex is not matching: `RR 1 Box 2`

Please help. I have not used positive look-behinds before and I am confused.

Comment: it's a C# User Defined Function being accessed from SQl Server. But I am testing using https://regex101.com/

So far everything else that worked on that site also worked in the UDF

Comment: Why it should match `RR 1` when there is no `Box` before it?

Comment: Your starting regex ends with `.*$`, which means any additional characters up to the end of the line.  Since that can match "23" and "OtherText 23", on what basis should the second two examples be rejected?  Is the trailing wildcard match in fact unwanted?

Comment: yeah .* is not required. it can end at 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches your input:

```
^RR\s+(?<RR>[0-9]+)(?:\s*Box\s*(?<POBox>[0-9]+))?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV0kO3/1).

C# regex:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^RR\s+(?<RR>[0-9]+)(?:\s*Box\s*(?<POBox>[0-9]+))?$");
var lst = new[] { "RR 1 Box 23", "RR 1", "RR 1 23", "RR 1 OtherText 23" };
var res = lst.Select(p => reg.IsMatch(p).ToString());
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I edited the post, I guess I was not clear enough. The above does not do what I want. It will not match RR 1

Comment: @user875615: Please check the regex now. I do not believe you need any look-behinds.